# Android, split gif to frames with ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, gif, android-ffmpeg

I need to split my gif file to separate frames of any format (gif, png, doesnt matter).

`ffmpeg -i path/to/gif -c:v gif -f image2 path/to/output$03d.gif`

this command really splits gif to frames, but only first frame have a normal quality. All other frames looks like some damaged images

[image]

library I use is com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2

What should Ido to get all frames with normal quality

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i path/to/gif -vsync 0 path/to/output%03d.png
```

Comment: now ~60% of frames have a normal quality, but other looks still like missed half of their pixels