# Android, Splitting GIFs with FFMPEG doesnt work

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I wanted to split animated gif files using [FFmpeg-Android-Java](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java), so I referenced this question [Android, split gif to frames with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39944653/android-split-gif-to-frames-with-ffmpeg)
 and wrote this code.

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/mothersday-toaster.gif";
        String cmd[] = {"-i",path,"-vsync","0","/storage/emulated/0/Download/output$03d.png"};

        try {
            // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
            ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {}

                @Override
                public void onProgress(String message) {}

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {Log.d("Q", "failed to convert");}

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {}

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {}
            });
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
        }
```

Although, It always gives me the "failed to convert" log. FFMPEG is already loaded. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: There's a typo in that OP and thus my answer. It should be `output%03d`

Comment: Thanks Gyan! With the permissions given, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the solution was quite easy.

I found the onProgress output saying that it needed permission so I noticed that I forgot to give my app the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission which was kind of a shame. And also, I changed the `output$03d` part to `output%03d`. Thanks [Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/gyan) for that advise.